# getting method last modified

Tags: c#, methods, attributes, last-modified

I have a question. I need to check when was a method last modified. I know how to check this for files but didn't find anything how can i check just a method. The assignment i have to do is the following:

> Write a LastModifiedAttribute that can be applied to a method. The
>   attribute should specify the date and programmer who last touched the
>   method and possibly an enumerated value of why the method was changed
>   (new feature, defect correction, etc.). Write a program that loads an
>   assembly and lists the classes and methods, sorted by their
>   lastmodified date.

If somebody can help with the last part of the assigment too about the programmer and the enumerated value i would appricate that too, but i'm mainly interested in the method last modified date. Thx anticipated

Comment: What revision control software are you using?

Comment: This is not a place to get homework done for you.  If you are having specific problems with your code, post the relevant code here and what is not working, and then we can try to help you.

Comment: BTW: This isn't a good use of your time. This type of functionality is built into all worthwhile revision control tools. e.g. `svn blame`, `git blame`, etc.

Comment: @dubstylee This doesn't smell like homework to me. If you substitute the word "assignment" with "task" in the question, it reads like the misguided attempt of a manager to point fingers at developers who broke code.

Comment: and a horrible way to track source revisions

Comment: not trying to make people do my homework, i pasted the assigment only to specify the context in which i have to use what i need. I just want to know if somebody knows a way to determine that last modified date for methods, That's all :)

Comment: I think what you're missing is the part about *writing* an *attribute that can be applied to a method*.  That should track the data you want as parameters.  Then, you can write a program that loads the assembly and reads the attributes.

Comment: @Asaph not using any software, only Reflection in C#

Comment: @NorbyKajtar I recommend that you use revision control. It's the "right way" to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EricHughes you're right, that's what i want to do, but i didn't find any way to get that last modified date

Comment: @Asaph I know it is, but as i said, it's an assignment, i can't use what i want unfortunetly so i have to make something happen the old fashioned way :)

Comment: @NorbyKajtar You can get it from your revision control software. If you aren't using any revision control software, you would have to rely on developers remembering to update an attribute every time they modify a method. And that's not reliable. Just use revision control and call it a day.

Comment: @NorbyKajtar: do you know what an [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is, how to create custom ones and use them?

Comment: @NorbyKajtar The last modified date would be a parameter that is set for the attribute when it is added to the method.  Just like the programmer's name and reason for changing.

Comment: Re: "The attribute should specify the date and programmer who last touched the method". To me this means that the programmer making the change *manually* writes the date and their name into the attribute in the source code, i.e., it does not mean you have to automatically detect when the change was made. I agree that this is a terrible way to track changes.

Comment: @NorbyKajtar Who gave you this "assignment"? Your manager or your teacher?

Comment: It seems like the purpose of this assignment is not to actually do change tracking, but to attempt to teach attributes.  It is, I'll admit, a horrible example of why one would want attributes (or Java's equivalent annotations)

Comment: @juharr thank you i thhink i got the idea now :)

Comment: @EricHughes yeah i do just didn't really understood what u wanted to say but the other answers helped me to do so :) i think i got it now

Comment: got it sorted out. I appreciate all the help :) and if anybody can tell me how to mark this answered from discussions only, i would appreciate it :) i'm new around here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a [custom attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56).

You can make it work on methods alone using

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
    public MyAttribute(string name, DateTime lastChanged, CustomEnum reason)
    {
        ...
```

This does not automatically find out when the method was last modified and why. That information is not present in the files, and your assignment doesn't say it is. You need a separate program to generate appropriate attribute tags from whatever version control system you use, or you can rely on the programmers to create appropriate tags.